# A with href being submit form?

Tags: javascript, html

Is this secure ?

```
<form id="form-id">

    <input type='text'name='name'>

    <input type='submit' value='Go' name='Go'/></form> 

    <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('form-id').submit();">submit</a>
```

If not, is there any other way to achieve same behaviour ?

Comment: There is no security difference in what you've posted. I use other elements to trigger form submit all the time.

Comment: This is HTML, not CSS.

Comment: If `JavaScript` is not enabled then it won't work and you can use the link in the place of `submit` button and can set event handler on the link, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't taking in any more or less user input (either at the browser or at the server) then you are with a regular submit button, so that approach doesn't impact security at all.

It does add a completely unnecessary dependancy on JavaScript and puts responsibility for submitting the form on a control not designed for submitting forms (and which won't show up in the Forms Mode of many screen reader software packages) so you shouldn't do that, just not for reasons related to security.

> is there any other way to achieve same behaviour ?

Yes, and you have it already:

```
<input type='submit' value='Go' name='Go'/>
```